# Every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Prove that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ is bounded.

In $\mathbb{R}$, this is a sketch of the proof that I recall:

Let {${a_k}$} be Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$, since $1\in\mathbb{R}$, $\exists N$ s.t. $\forall m,n>N$, $|a_n-A_N|<1\rightarrow$$|a_n|-|A_N|<|a_n-A_N|<1\iff|a_n|<1+|a_N|,\forall n>N-1$. Let $M = \max{|a_1|,|a_2|,\ldots,|a_N-1|,1+|a_N|}$. Then, $M$, $-M$ bound {$a_k$}.

A sequence is bounded in $\mathbb{C}$ if $\exists R\in\mathbb{R}$ and an integer $N$ s.t. $|z_n|<R$ $\forall, n>N$. Here's my attempt at the proof at hand then:

Let {${z_n}$} be Cauchy in $\mathbb{C}$. I want to show that there exists an R s.t. that definition above is satisfied. Is this R just the $M$ from the proof in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Does it? Where do you think it might stop working? You *have* to show us a little bit of what *you* have tried, for us to be able to help you with it.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95442/every-cauchy-sequence-in-a-metric-space-is-bounded

Comment: What is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Emir, how can possibly «this $R$ be just the $M$ from the proof in $\mathbb R$»?! In the proof in $\mathbb R$ there were $a$s, in the new instances there are $z$s... Can you please write out in detail what you have tried to do?

Answer (score 1):

To say that $-M$ and $M$ are respectively lower and upper bounds on the sequence $\{a_k\}$ is the same as saying $M$ is an upper bound on the sequence $\{|a_k|\}$.  Think about how all that applies to $\mathbb{R}$ and then to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Doesn't the proof implicitly use the lub property of $\mathbb{R}$? This clearly wouldnt work in $\mathbb{C}$ since it's not an ordered field.

Comment: I don't think you need that property.  This proof would work just as well for $\mathbb{Q}$.